# Hide status bar on launch image

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, statusbar

Is there a way to hide the status bar when the app's launch image is displayed ***and then bring it back?*** 
My app has a black status bar and the one displayed over the launch image is grey.

Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Use this code for hiding status bar:

**ObjectiveC:**

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES
 withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
```

**Swift:**

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarHidden(true, withAnimation: .Slide)
```

---

If you don't need status bar in the beginning. Add this setting *(`UIStatusBarHidden`)* in your Info `plist` file:

```
Status bar is initially hidden
```

with a value of `YES`.

Use this code anywhere in the app to show the status bar for that particular View Controller

**ObjectiveC:**

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
```

**Swift:**

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarHidden(false, withAnimation: .Slide)
```

Comment: Another thing to note is the `wantsFullScreen` property of UIViewController.

Comment: Where is the best place to put `UIApplication` code you've pasted?

Comment: I put that in did launch and I have all view controllers extending a base controller. I have a login in storyboard and a main storyboard. My base controller detects the storyboard type and if login type I make this call in view load. Put this call in your appdelegate:didlaunch and also in your viewdidload of your base controller(or view controller if you like to type a lot)

Comment: Status bar is initially hidden = YES in the infoplist did the trick thanks!

Comment: @HardikAmal add `application.isStatusBarHidden = false` in `application(didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)`

Comment: @rafalkitta in objective c?

Answer (score 16):

Just define a key in plist file will solve your problem

[image]

Happy Coding:)

Comment: Unfortunately this makes my whole app go fullscreen. While I only want the launch image to be full screen. I tried putting setStatusBarHidden:NO in the viewDidLoad but the status bar overlaps with the view :(

Answer (score 14):

You can initially add this key in the info.plist file: `status bar is initially hidden=YES`

Then in the app delegate, add this line in the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method:

```
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];
```

Answer (score 5):

To return it back:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Override point for customization after app launch

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Add below key to info.plist:

"Status bar is initially hidden" and select YES as value.

Comment: No, I want to bring it up then, not hide it forever. How do I do it?

Comment: @SergiusGee See my answer above, please.