# Prevent launch image overwriting of time on status bar

Tags: ios, statusbar, launchimage

I read that Apple prefers the launch image to be similar to your initial app screen to provide the user with the illusion of "instant on", and that somehow the status bar of the app while loading is hidden so that there is no conflict in time.

I am using a screenshot of the app as my launch image.

However, the status bar is not hidden at loading.  Instead, it is overwriting the image, which is okay for the static portion of the status bar which exactly matches the screenshot.  However, the time of the status bar is superimposed on the time in the screenshot, creating a blur.

Is it best practice to remove the time from the screenshot in Photoshop, or is there a way to hide the status bar at launch?  I've found [suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11864993/hide-status-bar-on-launch-image) to alter my plist file, but they seem a bit funky.

What is the best practice?

Comment: Hide the status bar on launch, its not very funky.

Comment: Reviewing SO questions, the various solutions seem dependent on which version of iOS you are using and some people report that accepted answers don't work with various configurations.  BTW is your google down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Launch image should not have the status bar on it because iOS actual status bar will be shown while the app is launching.

Also if you are using app screenshots, launch image should not contain any data or details that are shown to the user when the app is running.

Best practice is have something like a "background" that will be filled with actual data when the app is launched, giving the user the impression that the app launches faster.

See this example from Instagram app:

[image]