# iOS: Launch image gets wrinkled in the center during a call/recording/hot-spot session

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, launch-screen, launchimage

I use a set of launch images for my app and noticed that when I'm having a call, recording a voice note or sharing my Internet connection and put that activity in the background and launch my app, the launch screen is wrinkled in the center. Is there anything I can do to make the image look ok or is it just a standard iOS behavior?

[image]

Comment: Seems like an autolayout issue. Can you share the constraints applied to your launch screen ?

Comment: I don't load my launch screen from a .xib file, it's a set of images that I have in the Assets folder that I choose to load.

Comment: I had this same issue using launchscreen.storyboard, with a fixed height/width image centered in superview, with aspect fit turned on. Whatever Apple is doing with that call status bar is not compatible with launch screens.

Answer (score 13):

Just define a key in plist file will solve your problem

Status bar is initially hidden = YES

Answer (score 3):

OK, the solution I found is to hide status when launching the app, just like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11864993/hide-status-bar-on-launch-image)

Comment: Did you figure out a way to solve this without hiding the status bar initially and without using a launch storyboard ?

Comment: It is a real solution for what may be an Apple bug? It seems it's chopping a horizontal stripe out of the middle to make up for the status bar's height...  Mine happened even with fixed height/width constraints, aspect fit on an image view, and centered in superview using a launchscreen.storyboard.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like Apple "take" 4% of screen space from the middle of the screen (as far as I tested) to give it to status bar. Personally I faced this problem when using iPhone modem mode.

So if it is not critical for image to be centered vertically - the **solution** would be to **place image above/below this "4% middle screen area"**.

Examples when image is cropped:

[How image should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xbxC.png)(image centered vertically & horizontally, width & height are fixed size)

[How it actually looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjNuM.jpg)

Example when image looks as supposed to (but not centered) :

[Constraints example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykx6o.png)

[Image with new constraints example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BgpRh.jpg)